# How to get timestamp of tick precision in .NET / C#?

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp

Up until now I used `DateTime.Now` for getting timestamps, but I noticed that if you print `DateTime.Now` in a loop you will see that it increments in descrete jumps of approx. 15 ms. But for certain scenarios in my application I need to get the most accurate timestamp possible, preferably with tick (=100 ns) precision. Any ideas?

**Update:**

Apparently, `StopWatch` / `QueryPerformanceCounter` is the way to go, but it can only be used to measure time, so I was thinking about calling `DateTime.Now` when the application starts up and then just have `StopWatch` run and then just add the elapsed time from `StopWatch` to the initial value returned from `DateTime.Now`. At least that should give me accurate relative timestamps, right? What do you think about that (hack)?

**NOTE:**

`StopWatch.ElapsedTicks` is different from `StopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks`! I used the former assuming 1 tick = 100 ns, but in this case 1 tick = 1 / `StopWatch.Frequency`. So to get ticks equivalent to DateTime use `StopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks`. I just learned this the hard way.

**NOTE 2:**

Using the StopWatch approach, I noticed it gets out of sync with the real time. After about 10 hours, it was ahead by 5 seconds. So I guess one would have to resync it every X or so where X could be 1 hour, 30 min, 15 min, etc. I am not sure what the optimal timespan for resyncing would be since every resync will change the offset which can be up to 20 ms.

Comment: Surely the date/time set on the server isn't guaranteed to be accurate to 100ns, so I'm not sure what use having an "accurate" timestamp would be (as it's accuracy would only be that of the server)?

Comment: I need to time real-time financial data where accuracy is very important.

Comment: Obviously, I like your hack. :) But why does financial data need to be accurate to 100ns? I can understand this if you're timestamping data written to a database, and you need to discriminate between rows that would otherwise have exactly the same timestamp values.

Comment: I am performing calculations where this kind of accuracy is required. It also just feels wrong to see timestamps of trades that happen sequentially having the same time stamp when in reality you know they did not happen at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The value of the system clock that `DateTime.Now` reads is only updated every 15 ms or so (or 10 ms on some systems), which is why the times are quantized around those intervals.  There is an additional quantization effect that results from the fact that your code is running in a multithreaded OS, and thus there are stretches where your application is not "alive" and is thus not measuring the real current time.

Since you're looking for an ultra-accurate time stamp value (as opposed to just timing an arbitrary duration), the `Stopwatch` class by itself will not do what you need.  I think you would have to do this yourself with a sort of `DateTime`/`Stopwatch` hybrid.  When your application starts, you would store the current `DateTime.UtcNow` value (i.e. the crude-resolution time when your application starts) and then also start a `Stopwatch` object, like this:

```
DateTime _starttime = DateTime.UtcNow;
Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Then, whenever you need a high-resolution `DateTime` value, you would get it like this:

```
DateTime highresDT = _starttime.AddTicks(_stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks);
```

You also may want to periodically reset _starttime and _stopwatch, to keep the resulting time from getting too far out of sync with the system time (although I'm not sure this would actually happen, and it would take a long time to happen anyway).

**Update**: since it appears that Stopwatch *does* get out of sync with the system time (by as much as half a second per hour), I think it makes sense to reset the hybrid `DateTime` class based on the amount of time that passes between calls to check the time:

```
public class HiResDateTime
{
    private static DateTime _startTime;
    private static Stopwatch _stopWatch = null;
    private static TimeSpan _maxIdle = 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    public static DateTime UtcNow
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_stopWatch == null) || 
                (_startTime.Add(_maxIdle) < DateTime.UtcNow))
            {
                Reset();
            }
            return _startTime.AddTicks(_stopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks);
        }
    }

    private static void Reset()
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
}
```

If you reset the hybrid timer at some regular interval (say every hour or something), you run the risk of setting the time back before the last read time, kind of like a miniature Daylight Savings Time problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I came up with also when I read the other responses about StopWatch/QueryPerformanceCounter. Thanks for providing a code sample. I am sure, others will benefit from it also.

Comment: By the way, using DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now is actually important for timestamping. Otherwise, daylight savings time will hose you every Fall by suddenly throwing the timestamp values back by an hour.

Comment: Thanks. I already had to implement my own 'Date', 'Time' and 'DateAndTime' class to work around all the shortcomings of DateTime (e.g. no intrinsic support for time zones). It does seem extreme to reinvent the wheel with regards to Date/Time, but I am actually kind of suprised how bad DateTime was designed and implemented. You would think with all the resources and knowledge they have, they could have done way better.

Comment: <Yeah, this is what I came up with when I read> I wouldn't underestimate my previous comment about skew. Especially when the documentation for QueryPerformanceCounter talks about bugs in the BIOS and HAL. :)

Comment: @binary: as I said in my answer, I'm not entirely sure my DateTime/Stopwatch hybrid actually *would* get out of sync with just an ordinary DateTime, since I *think* they're ultimately driven by the same underlying mechanism. DateTime is quantized to 15 ms because that's how often the system time is updated, but the underlying mechanism doing the updating is the same mechanism underlying Stopwatch </THEORY>.

Comment: @Hermann: do you know about the System.TimeZone class? (just discovered it myself)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I am using TimeZoneInfo class internally. MSDN says to use this one instead of TimeZone. TimeZoneInfo supports conversion across all time zones while TimeZone supports only Local and UTC (not any different from DateTime).

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I just discovered a bug in my code (and your code sample). Please see my "NOTE" in my updated question. You might want to updated your code sample. Thanks.

Comment: @binarycoder: I'll find out if it gets out of sync (my application is going to run for at least 10 hours) and post it here.

Comment: @Hermann: thanks, I edited my code. I should have mentioned in my original answer that this code was not tested.

Comment: @binarycoder: You were right. It does get out of sync. I noticed it was about 5 seconds ahead after 10 hours. I guess I'll have to resync it every X or so, I am not sure what to use for X. 1 hour? 30 min? 1 min?

Comment: @Hermann: that is a very interesting result. It seems to suggest that Stopwatch, while having a very high resolution, is not very accurate.

Comment: @Hermann: I'd go with resetting it whenever it's been idle for more than a given length of time (see my update).  I don't know if 10 seconds is exactly the best idle time, but I don't think it hurts to reset it that frequently.

Comment: @Hermann: I've been running a similar test for the last two hours (without the reset correction), and the Stopwatch-based timer is only running about 400 ms ahead after 2 hours, so the skew itself appears to be variable (but still pretty severe). I'm pretty surprised that the skew is this bad; I guess this is why Stopwatch is in System.Diagnostics.

Comment: If you need a thread-safe version, see the answer by Ian Mercer below.

Comment: @FrankHileman: as long as readers understand that Ian's answer has accuracy limited to 16 ms by Datetime.  It would be better to modify this answer to be thread-safe.

Comment: An interesting enhancement would be to modify continuously.  On a given system, track the skew of Stopwatch vs DateTime. So rather than making sudden jumps to reset after an idle period, adjust every returned value based on a multiplier (that will be very slightly above or below 1, depending on the system's drift; e.g. 1.0000001). Instead of doing "reset" after idle, which could cause up to 16 ms "jump" in your time, poll datetime periodically, making a microscopic change to your multiplier each time (and set a time-offset, so that new multiplier only applies to time after the change).

Comment: Or as an alternative, have a separate thread periodically do the reset. This other thread must be asleep most of the time, then wake up and poll DateTime fairly rapidly, to find out (more accurately than to the nearest 16ms) when DateTime changes to a new value. When it sees DateTime change, it reads the stopwatch value. Now it has a correspondence between an "edge" when DateTime transitions, and a stopwatch time. So can calculate an accurate offset for future time results.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - Your UtcNow <-> Stopwatch synchronization approach isn't correct. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38127282/344638

Comment: This guy seems to have fixed all the threading issues in this answer and has come up with an even more accurate clock, http://www.nimaara.com/2016/07/06/high-resolution-clock-in-net/

Answer (score 23):

To get a high-resolution tick-count, please, use the static Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()-method:

```
long tickCount = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
DateTime highResDateTime = new DateTime(tickCount);
```

just take a look at the .NET Source Code:

```
    public static long GetTimestamp() {
        if(IsHighResolution) {
            long timestamp = 0;    
            SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceCounter(out timestamp);
            return timestamp;
        }
        else {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        }   
    }
```

Source Code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,69c6c3137e12dab4

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I always trying to find the shortest way to solve a problem by using the available features of the .NET framework. And share it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on .NET 4.5.2 and Win 10 x64. Datetimes have year of 0001.

Answer (score 20):

*[The accepted answer does not appear to be thread safe, and by its own admission can go backwards in time causing duplicate timestamps, hence this alternative answer]*

If what you really care about (per your comment) is in fact, a unique timestamp that is allocated in strict ascending order and which corresponds as closely as possible to the system time, you could try this alternative approach:

```
public class HiResDateTime
{
   private static long lastTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
   public static long UtcNowTicks
   {
       get
       {
           long orig, newval;
           do
           {
               orig = lastTimeStamp;
               long now = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
               newval = Math.Max(now, orig + 1);
           } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange
                        (ref lastTimeStamp, newval, orig) != orig);

           return newval;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608980/how-to-ensure-a-timestamp-is-always-unique/14369695#14369695 for my thoughts.

Comment: For the record, I didn't admit that my method can go backwards in time. I wrote: "If you reset the hybrid timer at some regular interval (say every hour or something), you run the risk of setting the time back before the last read time", which was an explanation of why I chose *not* to reset the timer at some regular interval. My solution was definitely not thread safe, however, and I like the non-duplication feature of your solution.

Comment: The limitation of this solution is that its *resolution* is limited by DateTime to 1ms or 16ms (depending on hardware).  While the timestamps will be unique, they will not measure ticks precisely. @MusiGenesis approach will give more precise measurements.

Answer (score 13):

These suggestions all look too hard! If you're on Windows 8 or Server 2012 or higher, use `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` as follows:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
static extern void GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out long filetime);

public DateTimeOffset GetNow()
{
    long fileTime;
    GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out fileTime);
    return DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime(fileTime);
}
```

This has much, much better accuracy than `DateTime.Now` without any effort.

See MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Of course all those answers were written before Windows 8 / Server 2012 even existed. And even today, to assume customers have 8 / 2012 is not a good assumption to make, for most code.

Answer (score 8):

It does return the most accurate date and time known to the operating system.

The operating system also provides higher resolution timing through `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` (.NET `Stopwatch` class). These let you time an interval but do not give you date and time of day. You might argue that these would be able to give you a very accurate time and day, but I am not sure how badly they skew over a long interval.

Comment: Would it make sense to call DateTime.Now when the application starts up and then just have StopWatch run and then just add the elapsed tiem from StopWatch to the initial value returned from DateTime.Now to get a more accurate timestamp?

Comment: Hermann, the difference in the values will be accurate, but the base (DateTime.Now) will still suffer the ~20ms accuracy. So will the absolute values you will get.

Comment: Yes, but considering that your system time is probably not synchronized perfectly anyway that offset wouldn't make much of a difference. At least that way the relative timestamps are more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

1). If you need high resolution absolute accuracy: you can't use `DateTime.Now`
when it is based on a clock with a 15 ms interval (unless it
is possible "slide" the phase).

Instead, an external source of better resolution absolute
accuracy time (e.g. ntp), `t1` below, could be combined with the high
resolution timer (StopWatch / QueryPerformanceCounter).

---

2). If you just need high resolution:

Sample `DateTime.Now` (`t1`) once together with a value from the
high resolution timer (StopWatch / QueryPerformanceCounter)
(`tt0`).

If the current value of the high resolution timer is `tt` then the
current time, `t`, is:

```
t = t1 + (tt - tt0)
```

---

3). An alternative could be to disentangle absolute time and
order of the financial events: one value for absolute time
(15 ms resolution, possibly off by several minutes) and one
value for the order (for example, incrementing a value by one each
time and store that). The start value for the order can be
based on some system global value or be derived from the
absolute time when the application starts.

This solution would be more robust as it is not dependent on
the underlying hardware implementation of the clocks/timers
(that may vary betweens systems).

Answer (score 2):

The 15 ms (actually it can be 15-25 ms) accuracy is based on the Windows 55 Hz/65 Hz timer resolution. This is also the basic TimeSlice period. Affected are [Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), [Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx), [Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), etc.

To get accurate intervals you should use the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). It will use high-resolution if available. Try the following statements to find out:

```
Console.WriteLine("H = {0}", System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.IsHighResolution);
Console.WriteLine("F = {0}", System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency);
Console.WriteLine("R = {0}", 1.0 /System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency);
```

I get R=6E-08 sec, or 60 ns. It should suffice for your purpose.

Comment: -1 because the 15ms quantization is based on the Windows scheduler. The ~55Hz timer resolution is from an older, crude timer mechanism that fires off 18 events per second.

Comment: The resolution I am getting on my system is about 2.8 ticks (2.79365114840015E-07), which is pretty good. Especially compared to DateTime.NowUtc, it's 50,000 times more accurate.

Comment: Musical Genius, 1/55 = 18 ms, so what's the diff?

Comment: @Henk: ouch ("Musical Genius"). :)

Comment: @Henk: sorry, I misread your original answer as saying the 15 ms was based on the Windows 55 **ms** timer resolution (which happened to be the resolution of the old-school 18 **Hz** timer). My bad.

Answer (score 2):

This is too much work for something so simple. Just insert a DateTime in your database with the trade. Then to obtain trade order use your identity column which should be an incrementing value.

If you are inserting into multiple databases and trying to reconcile after the fact then you will be mis-calculating trade order due to any slight variance in your database times (even ns increments as you said)

To solve the multiple database issue you could expose a single service that each trade hits to get an order. The service could return a DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks and an incrementing trade number.

Even using one of the solutions above anyone conducting trades from a location on the network with more latency could possibly place trades first (real world), but they get entered in the wrong order due to latency. Because of this the trade must be considered placed at the database, not at users' consoles.

Comment: While this does give trade order, it does not give *sub-ms accuracy* to timestamps, as requested by OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the following regarding **MusiGenesis** Answer for *the re-sync timing.*

Meaning: What time should I use to re-sync ( the `_maxIdle` in **MusiGenesis** answer's)

You know that with this solution you are not perfectly accurate, thats why you re-sync.
But also what you implicitly want is the same thing as **Ian Mercer** solution's:

> a unique timestamp that is allocated in strict ascending order

Therefore the amount of time between two re-sync ( `_maxIdle` Lets call it **SyncTime**) should be function of 4 things:

- the `DateTime.UtcNow` resolution
- the ratio of accuracy you want
- the precision level you want
- An estimation of the out-of-sync ratio of your machine

Obviously the first constraint on this variable would be :

**out-of-sync ratio <= accuracy ratio**

For example : I dont want my accuracy to be worst than 0.5s/hrs or 1ms/day etc... (in bad English: I dont want to be more wrong than 0.5s/hrs=12s/day).

So you cannot achieve a better accuracy than what the Stopwatch offer you on your PC. It depends on your out-of-sync ratio, which might not be constant.

Another constraint is the minimum time between two resync:

**Synctime >= `DateTime.UtcNow` resolution**

Here accuracy and precision are linked because if you using a high precision (for example to store in a DB) but a lower accuracy, You might break **Ian Mercer statement** that is the strict ascending order.

Note: *It seems DateTime.UtcNow may have a bigger default Res than 15ms (1ms on my machine)* Follow the link:
[High accuracy DateTime.UtcNow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/05/16/high-precision-datetime-utcnow-on-windows-server-os.aspx)

Let's take an example:

Imagine the out-of-sync ratio commented above.

> After about 10 hours, it was ahead by 5 seconds.

Say I want a microsec precision. My timer res is 1ms *(see above Note)*

So point by point:

- the `DateTime.UtcNow` resolution : **1ms**
- accuracy ratio >= out-of-sync ratio,
  lets take the most accurate possible so : **accuracy ratio = out-of-sync ratio**
- the precision level you want : **1 microsec**
- An estimation of the out-of-sync ratio of your machine : **0.5s/hour** (this is also my accuracy)

If you reset every 10s, imagine your at 9.999s, 1ms before reset.
Here you make a call during this interval. The time your function will plot is ahead by : 0.5/3600*9.999s eq 1.39ms.
You would display a time of 10.000390sec. After UtcNow tick, if you make a call within the 390micro sec, your will have a number inferior to the previous one. Its worse if this out-of-sync ratio is random depending on CPU Load or other things.

Now let's say I put **SyncTime** at its minimum value > I resync every 1ms

Doing the same thinking would put me Ahead of time by 0.139 microsec < inferior to the precision I want. Therefore if I call the function at 9.999 ms, so 1microsec before reset I will plot 9.999. And just after I will plot 10.000. I will have a good order.

So here the other constraint is : accuracy-ratio x SyncTime < precision level , lets say to be sure because number can be rounded up that **accuracy-ratio x SyncTime < precision level/2** is good.

The issue is resolved.

**So a Quick recap would be :**

- Retrieve your timer resolution.
- Compute an estimate of the out-of-sync ratio.
- accuracy ratio >= out-of-sync ratio estimate , **Best accuracy = out-of-sync ratio**
- Choose your Precision Level considering the following:
- **timer-resolution <= SyncTime <= PrecisionLevel/(2*accuracy-ratio)**
- The best Precision you can achieve is **timer-resolution*2*out-of-sync ratio**

For the above ratio (0.5/hr) the correct SyncTime would be 3.6ms, so rounded down to **3ms**.

With the above ratio and the timer resolution of 1ms. If you want a **one-tick Precision level** (0.1microsec), you need an out-of-sync ratio of no more than : **180ms/hour.**

In its last answer to its own answer **MusiGenesis** state:

> @Hermann: I've been running a similar test for the last two hours (without the reset correction), and the Stopwatch-based timer is only running about 400 ms ahead after 2 hours, so the skew itself appears to be variable (but still pretty severe). I'm pretty surprised that the skew is this bad; I guess this is why Stopwatch is in System.Diagnostics. – MusiGenesis

*So the Stopwatch accuracy is close to 200ms/hour, almost our 180ms/hour. Is there any link to why our number and this number are so close ? Dont know. But this accuracy is enough for us to achieve Tick-Precision*

The Best PrecisionLevel: For the example above it is **0.27 microsec.**

However what happen if I call it multiple times between 9.999ms and the re-sync.

2 calls to the function could end-up with the same TimeStamp being returned the time would be 9.999 for both (as I dont see more precision). To circumvent this, you cannot touch the precision level because it is Linked to SyncTime by the above relation. So you should implement **Ian Mercer** solution's for those case.

Please don't hesitate to comment my answer.

Comment: MusiGenesis's approach is superior, as long as (1) Stopwatch's drift is small (which it is), and (2) there are gaps in the requests, long enough to perform the reset. The one feature he is missing is the "auto-increment" from Ian's (which could easily be added). Under no circumstances should one use Ian's by itself, if you care about tick accuracy: DateTime is only accurate to 16 ms.

Comment: If (2) is a problem, because there aren't enough gaps, then MG's solution needs to be adjusted to do "continuous correction": every call should check whether Now has changed from the previous call. If it has, then reset the timer, but use Ian's "Max(Now, lasttimestamp+1) to make sure you always increase.

Answer (score 0):

If need the timestamp to perform benchmarks use [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) which has much better precision than DateTime.Now.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the best way to solve this issue:

```cs
long timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

Comment: how does this answer compare/contrast with the other 10 answers here?  Can you please elaborate why this might be better?

Comment: Jason, first of all:
1.) it should work faster
2.) it does not contain any error-prone logic as the so-called green answer does (like recalling DateTime.UtcNow can get us back in the past and other issues regarding the multithreading environment).
3.) this way of implementing will be more supportable.
4.) and the last one: I did not really test other answers, but I suspect they will not be working in some possible corner cases at all.

Comment: That's good Vladimir.  I only suggest that it is good to state these ideas when you post your solution.  It will be helpful for others who come across your answer.

Comment: I am sorry if my answer is not obvious. So to be clear my exact point is
to use this DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
instead of this HiResDateTime.TimestampNow;
Thank you!