# Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() C# equivalent in NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, stopwatch

I'm trying to get `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` equivalent in NodeJS, but I only managed this:

Javascript:

```
(Date.now()*10000)+621355968000000000; //returns 637414085816080000
```

C#

```
Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() // returns 6618676876650
```

**Note** that the results are different

Comment: Trying to get the same absolute value is not sensible, it is not based on the date.  A hard reboot of the machine tends to reset the counter back to 0.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725691/how-to-get-a-microtime-in-node-js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before discussing, You should be aware that :

- `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` has the ticks since the computer
  **booted** if the `Stopwatch` class uses the system timer. [@jonskeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1438667/1743997), [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp?view=net-5.0#remarks)
- `Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.
  [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp)

Now, If you want the same values for both, You should share a similar **base** time and then count the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

`Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` gives back results specific to the machine where you run it. Comparing it to Javascript-style timestamps won't work.