# Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() produced different results on linux vs windows

Tags: c#, linux, windows, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am hoping someone can explain to my why the function below produces incredibly different results on linux vs windows.

If I have this little snippet of code:

```cs
var elapsed = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

Thread.Sleep(1001); // lets sleep for one second

var ts = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond; 
var result = ts  - elapsed  > 10000L // roughly 10 seconds
```

On a windows environment `result` is `false` <-- expected result

But on a linux environment `result` is `true` <-- what....why?

I have read that Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() is dependent on the processor. But this seems excessive.

As far as I can tell GetTimestamp produces wildly different values on Windows vs Linux.

e.g. in my case running the code above

On Windows `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` produces a value of roughly in range of `165100732`

On Linux `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` produces a value more than a 200x bigger e.g. `349232049523`

So I can see why `result` is different i.e. on Windows it records a elapsed duration of 1 second but on Linux is records an elapsed duration of close to 100 seconds. So that part is fine.

So question boils down to why does `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` produce such wildly different numbers between the two environments?

Comment: OR (probably more likely)... Why does `Thread.Sleep(1001)` take so long to wake up on Linux?

Comment: Are you sure your last line is correct? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond?view=net-5.0 that states TicksPerMillisecond is 10000, so I don't think 10000 is roughly 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a bit more digging I found that I was performing the millisecond calculation incorrectly when using `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()`.

After updating the code as below it started to behave consistently.

```cs
var elapsed = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / (Stopwatch.Frequency / 1000);

Thread.Sleep(1001); // lets sleep for one second

var ts = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() /  (Stopwatch.Frequency / 1000); 
var result = ts  - elapsed  > 10000L // roughly 10 seconds
```

The answer is thanks to comment by Jens on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180635/737071)