# Random class generating same sequence

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have a method which I am using to generate random strings by creating random integers and casting them to `char`

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(int minLength, int maxLength)
        {
            var length = GenerateRandomNumber(minLength, maxLength);

            var builder = new StringBuilder(length);

            var random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append((char) random.Next(255));
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

The problem is that when I call this method frequently, it is creating the same sequence of values, as the docs already says:

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to **make the seed value
>   time-dependent**, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random.

As you can see I am making the seed time dependent and also creating a new instance of `Random` on each call to the method. Even though, my Test is still failing.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GenerateRandomStringTest()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var string1 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(10, 100);
                var string2 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(10, 20);
                if (string1.Contains(string2))
                    throw new InternalTestFailureException("");
            }
        }
```

How could I make sure that independently of the frequency on which I call the method, the sequence will "always" be different?

Comment: You simply can't when calling it in such a tight loop. [According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) there are 10,000 ticks per millisecond. Your loop probably takes less than that to execute. Therefore, `DateTime.Now.Ticks` will be the same for every iteration. You will probably have to find a webservice or something that gives you a random number... but that won't be quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is failing because the `GenerateRandomString` function completes too soon for the `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to change. On most systems it is [quantized at either 10 or 15 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1416139/335858), which is more than enough time for a modern CPU to generate a sequence of 100 random characters.

Inserting a small delay in your test should fix the problem:

```
var string1 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(10, 100);
Thread.Sleep(30);
var string2 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively doing the same as `Random`'s default constructor. It's using [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx). Take a look at the example in [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Random` constructor. It shows that inserting a `Thread.Sleep` between the initialization of the different `Random` instances, will yield different results.

If you really want to get different values, I suggest you change to a seed value that's **not** time-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

dasblinkenlight has given why this is happening.

Now you should do this to overcome this problem

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(Random random , int minLength, 
                                                  int maxLength)
{
    var length = GenerateRandomNumber(random , minLength, maxLength);

    var builder = new StringBuilder(length);   

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
         builder.Append((char) random.Next(255));

    return builder.ToString();
}

public void GenerateRandomStringTest()
{
    Random rnd = New Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var string1 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(rnd, 10, 100);
        var string2 = Utilitaries.GenerateRandomString(rnd, 10, 20);
        if (string1.Contains(string2))
            throw new InternalTestFailureException("");
    }
}
```